# obiee12c limit in the number of table prompts that can be used in the analysis

Tags: prompt, obiee

I would like to know if the number of TABLE PROMPTS that can be used in an analysis in OBIEE12C are limited to only two or if this can be configured somehow.

I want to enter four fields as table prompts but I am not able to do it. I can only add two.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no limitation to only 2 table prompts in OBIEE.

From what you described, your issue can be related to

- A limitation in the quantity of data that is being used (in this case OBIEE should return an error when you drag and drop a new column)
- Or more likely, it's related to the browser you're using to develop. Try to switch to Internet Explorer or Firefox.

Comment: Hi Taísa,  I have just tried with another browser (Firefox instead of Chrome) and the problem has been resolved! Thanks a lot for your valuable tip!! ;-)

Comment: Great! From my experience, Chrome is the worst browser for OBIEE (to develop or to visualize the dashboards).

Comment: Good to know! :-)